# Why does my "Export to CAD" script work in Python 3.7, but not in 2.7?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-2.7, error-000732, python-3.7

I've written a script that iterates through all feature classes in a dataset in a geodatabase and writes them to separate dwg-files. In this case 230 feature classes. If I run the script in Python 2.7.18 it only converts some of the files (and the amount seems to be random depending on during which day/session I run it). The other files get the following error:

> Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.                           ERROR 000732:
> Input Features: Dataset xxxxx does not exist or is not
> supported

I tried everything I could think of, and find on the internet, but nothing helped. It only started working correctly when I changed the script to Python 3.7.9. I've run the 2.7.18 script from IDLE and 3.7.9 from IDLE (ArcGIS Pro), if that matters.

I based my script on the ArcGIS desktop "Export to CAD" example code. This is the code I ran (Python 2.7.18):

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Set workspace
env.workspace = r'C:\\test\\test.gdb\\dataset'

# Set local variables
output_type = "DWG_R2018"
output_filepath = r'C:\\test\\CAD_\\'

for feature in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():  
    print feature
    try:
        # Process: Export to CAD
        in_features = feature
        output_file = output_filepath + feature +".dwg"
        arcpy.ExportCAD_conversion(in_features, output_type, output_file, "USE_FILENAMES_IN_TABLES", "OVERWRITE_EXISTING_FILES", "")
        print arcpy.GetMessages()
    except:
       # If an error occurs while running a tool print the message
        print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

The only thing I changed when running it in 3.7.9 was the print syntax, i.e. use parenthesis: "print (feature)".

This drives me nuts. Why does this code work in Python 3.7.9, but only partially in 2.7.18?

Comment: Could it be something to do with the input data? For example its an empty feature class? In 2.7 that crashes the code but in 3.7 it runs without error?

Comment: The input feature classes are not empty, but there could perhaps be something else wrong with them. They have been merged and clipped with the geoprocessing tools (with another script) and perhaps something happened there? I checked a few of the dwg-files, that did not convert with 2.7 but did with 3.7, and they seem to have converted without any problems.

Comment: I think you should remove your try/except statements while you're testing.  They may be masking otherwise useful error messages.

Comment: If I remove the try/except I get no error messages, it executes the code as if it worked properly, but it only exports 23 files (and also only print messages for these 23 features)

Comment: What version of ArcMap are you using? Could this be less bound to Python and more bound to Desktop? BTW: Using raw formatting means *not* having to double the backslashes.

Comment: There are so many potential causes, you 'll probably need to work this with Tech Support. Low-hangling fruit would include massive layers that generate corrupt documents.  Where possible, you really ought to be using 64-bit geoprocessing, which should be giving you the same benefits of the 64-bit Py3/

Comment: You say "it only exports 23 files" so what happens when you test with your loop hardwired to individually test your 23rd, 24th and 25th files (with your try/except removed)?